# Not understand firestore rules stop working

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-security

I have been using firestore rules for a while and I started to get a extrange error. It started one week ago.

Here is the rule of the collection I have:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /us/{usId}  { 
        allow get: if signedIn();
        allow list: if false;       
        allow create: if true;      
        allow update: if false;
        allow delete: if false;         
    }
}
```

and when I try to write a document like this, i get the following error:

```
_firestore.collection('us').doc(value.us).set({'nombre': ["ejemplo"]})
```

error:

```
[Firestore]: Write failed at us/mCvu3AQy8ZeTE7Ph1wg8334Sxyn2: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null} 
E/flutter ( 9286): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

and it makes no sense to me. I try simulating it and I am able to do a write.

What do I miss?

Comment: Does a document with that already exists? If yes, then create rule will fail iirc.

Comment: Nope, that document does not exist

Comment: Haven't you enabled `AppCheck`? I had a similar issue when trying to enforce `Firestore` access with `AppCheck`.

Comment: Nope, app check is unenforced for Firestore

Comment: I don't know why, but rules are considering that set is an operation of update. I have changed update conditional and now i am able to create new documents. Somehow it is weird and I don't really get why.